# Remove conflicting polygons and restore original

Tags: maya

I'm a newbie to Maya and downloaded a model to play with. I think the surface  I have is a Mesh that I performed a bunch of operations on and messed up. Is there anyway I can restore this to a simple rectangle? If I can't, is there a way to make a new rectangle with the exact same size and location?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One fool-proof way is to reopen the model if you didn't make a lot of changes to it. Another way is to delete your history in Maya.